# Como eu faço um search em vários campos Checkbox?

Tags: jquery

Tenho vários Checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="chkItem" name="Selected" value="1" /> A
   </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="chkItem" name="Selected" value="2" /> B
   </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="chkItem" name="Selected" value="3" /> C
   </label>
</div>
```

Como eu faço para criar um "Search" busque a letra "C" por exemplo e que esconda todos os outros checkbox ?

Comment: Não entendi o que você realmente quer fazer

Comment: @ThallysonDias, eu tenho muitos checkbox, eu queria só fazer um filtro com um input,para o usuário buscar o que ele quer, deixando "hide" todos os outros, e dando show apenas no que ele buscou

Comment: Qual seu objetivo? É clicar em no `checkbox C` e esconder os outros? É clicar e procurar letras "C" em um texto? É xingar todas as pessoas no Facebook com nomes que contenham a letra "C"? :P. Pode especificar um pouco mais sua pergunta?

Comment: @gabrielhof expliquei no comentário acima

Comment: Seria algo semelhante a isso? http://jsfiddle.net/h5z7zxod/

Comment: @gabrielhof, obrigado pela ajuda, mas não é isso não, Eu tenho 100 Checkbox, como os acima, quero por um input text para buscar apenas o "C" por exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tinha uma busca dessas aqui e foi facil adaptar no seu html:

```
$("#search").bind("change keyup", function() {
    var search_str = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (search_str != "") {
        $(".checkbox").hide();
        $(".checkbox").filter(function( index ) {
            return $( this ).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search_str) != -1;
        }).show();
    } else {
        $(".checkbox").show();
    }
});
```

Funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qshvvhnx/)

Comment: Isso mesmo Jader :DD Obrigadão, vai me ajudar e muito isso hehe